# Unable to match font weights with google fonts and react styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, google-fonts

I'm trying the following style below. The issue is the actual result font-weight is no where close to the mock-up. How can I ensure I get the right style?

https://fonts.google.com/specimenTab?standard-styles#standard-styles

```
const LogoH1 = styled.span`
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
`
```

## Design Tool (Adobe XD)

[image]

## Result

[image]

I'm using Gatsby to connect the fonts:

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `Montserrat`,
        ],
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Show me how you connect the fonts. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: Added the snippet

Comment: I don't know Gatsby. But the official website says to specify the weight of the font. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/

Comment: I tried this as well to no avail

Comment: Like this? 'Montserrat\:900'

Comment: I don't see how to specify italic/semi bold, etc.

Comment: Ok, seems like bold is working now! But unsure about specifying the other style types.

Answer (score 1):

```
plugins: [
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      `Montserrat\:400,500,600,700,800,900`,
    ],
  }
}],
```